# mysql result not showing all column values

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I'm trying to fetching data from mysql database (i use php myadmin from xampp) with odbc driver 8.0 ansi, connection work properly but the record not showing all column value from database

My excel result:
[image: My excel result]
but in phpmyadmin the "resignation_reason" not null
[image: in phpmyadmin]

my vba code like this:

```
Sub LoadData()
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim record_set As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim column_name As ADODB.Field
Dim i As Integer

conn.ConnectionString = "driver={mysql odbc 8.0 ansi driver};server=server;port=3306;database=db;uid=user;password=password;"
conn.ConnectionTimeout = 3
conn.Open

record_set.Open "select * from employee_noc", conn

For Each column_name In record_set.Fields
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Value = column_name.Name
    i = i + 1
Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset record_set

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting the string columns in your select query. It should work.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, CAST(Col3 AS VARCHAR(8)) AS Col3 FROM TableName
```